# Escapar comillas PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

estoy haciendo un `insert` en `sql` y necesitaba cambiar las comillas simples, ya que por ejemplo un el nombre O'Connor rompe la estructura. 
Lo he intentado poniendo:

```
str_replace("'", "\'", $cadena);
```

Tambien con:

```
htmlspecialchars($contenido->texto, ENT_NOQUOTES)
```

Y no me funcionan. Éste último si me convierte las comillas simples, pero también convierte los símbolos `<`, `>`, etc, y no deben convertirse.

Ah, y también he probado con `addslashes`pero nada...

Muchas gracias de antemano!!

Comment: No entiendo porque ese nombre te rompe la estructura. que error tira? si ese nombre se inserta como una variable, no deberia pasar nada con el query

Comment: Puedes dar más información, por ejemplo la variable que utilizas para realizar el insert (Me imagino que utilizas;  **new mysqli()** y posteriormente $conn->query($sql))

Comment: No tengo ni idea; el `values` está encerrado con comillas simples, pero no puedo cambiarlo porque tengo código HTML e interfiere

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En tu caso debes usar barra doble para escapar las comillas de la variable. La función **mysql_real_escape_string** lo hace automaticamente aunque necesita tener una conexión establecida previamente. Si deseas escapar la cadena antes de conectar la base de datos puedes implementar tu propio método, siempre y cuando tengas en cuenta factores como inyección SQL (Documentado en PHP.Net)

```
function sql_escape_mimic($inp) { 
    if(is_array($inp)) 
        return array_map(__METHOD__, $inp); 

    if(!empty($inp) && is_string($inp)) { 
        return str_replace(array('\\', "\0", "\n", "\r", "'", '"', "\x1a"), array('\\\\', '\\0', '\\n', '\\r', "\\'", '\\"', '\\Z'), $inp); 
    } 

    return $inp; 
}
```

Referencia
http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php